# How to anchor the SnackBar at the top and keep the screen clickable?

Tags: flutter, snackbar

I was able to add the `SnackBar` at the top using the Widget provided by flutter, but the margin overflow the content that's under the `SnackBar`.

That basically "disable" the screen while the `SnackBar` is being displayed.

Test yourself on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/8af603c66f9fa43aac77f996e0e4b587)

Follows a print of the [guidelines tool](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/inspector#show-guidelines) on a test app:

[image]

Comment: Can you use MaterialBanner widget instead?

Comment: No, I should use the snackbar, or another solution that have a closer behavior